# SpringBoot > Programmatically add Jetty server connector ports at runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

Using `spring-boot` and `jetty`, I'd like to be able to configure my application to listen on additional ports, which are programmatically **added at runtime** (+ removed?).

**What I've tried:**

I've followed [this tutorial](http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2015/03/10/spring_boot_jetty_multi_port.html), which allows me to listen on multiple ports. This works perfectly, but unfortunately only works at startup only.

I've tried `@Autowiring` a [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.17.v20160517/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) class into a service, so that I can add connectors - I got the error `No qualifying bean of type [org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server] found ...`

**build.gradle (dependencies**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

...

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-proxy:9.2.17.v20160517"

...
```

Not sure what to try from here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get hold of the Jetty `Server` from Boot's `JettyEmbeddedServletContainer` which is available from the `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext`. Once you've got hold of the `Server` you can then add new connectors to it using Jetty's API.

Here's an example that adds a new connector in response to the `ApplicationReadyEvent` being published:

```
@Bean
public JettyCustomizer jettyCustomizer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext context) {
    return new JettyCustomizer(
            (JettyEmbeddedServletContainer) context.getEmbeddedServletContainer());
}

static class JettyCustomizer implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private final JettyEmbeddedServletContainer container;

    JettyCustomizer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        Server server = this.container.getServer();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8081);
        server.addConnector(connector);
        try {
            connector.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to start connector", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You should see in the logs the default connector starting on port 8080 and then the second connector starting on 8081:

```
2016-08-16 10:28:57.476  INFO 71330 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started ServerConnector@64bc21ac{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-08-16 10:28:57.478  INFO 71330 --- [           main] .s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer : Jetty started on port(s) 8080 (http/1.1)
2016-08-16 10:28:57.482  INFO 71330 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started ServerConnector@664a9613{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2016-08-16 10:28:57.483  INFO 71330 --- [           main] sample.jetty.SampleJettyApplication      : Started SampleJettyApplication in 1.838 seconds (JVM running for 2.132)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491231/spring-boot-how-to-dynamically-add-new-tomcat-connector

Comment: Hi, do you know which dependency to add to get JettyEmbeddedServletContainer? The spring-boot-starter-jetty artifact does not provide access to this class, and can't find anything on maven central. Thanks.

Comment: @TomasAntos this answer was written in the days of Spring Boot 1.x. In 2.x, you can use `JettyWebServer` which can be retrieved from `org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerApplicationContext.getWebServer()`